# Does WSO2 Identity server generate token with empty scope request

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

While going through the WSO2 IS documents, I can observe that scope is an Optional parameter in /oauth2/token request. But when I remove scope from the request, I get Invalid Scope! error. Is this expected behavior?
Can someone point me to the correct document for the same.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please mention the IS version that you try and the oauth2 grant type that you used ?

Comment: Grant type- client_credentials and IS version-5.11

Comment: I tried the client credential grant without requesting any scope in IS-5.11.0 and it works perfectly. ```curl --location 'https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <base64encoded clinet id:secret>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'```

Comment: If the above-mentioned curl doesn't work, could you please  invok GET application https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/application-rest-api/#/Applications/getApplication REST API and GET application's oidc config https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/application-rest-api/#/Inbound%20Protocols%20-%20OAuth%20%2F%20OIDC/getInboundOAuthConfiguration and share them in the question by masking sensitive info

Comment: So you are saying the expected behavior is token would get created without scope in request. Right? Could u please share the token generated for reference

Comment: Yes. This is the response I get for the above mentioned token request 
`
{
    "access_token": "d90f322f-59d9-39b8-8555-f049fa318397",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3566
}
`

Comment: Ok. Thank you. so a token with no scope claim would be created right?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to generate a token without requesting any scope. Try the curl which I have posted in the above comment. If it's not working for your case, create new oauth/oidc app without making any additional confogurations and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Client Credential grant type without scopes

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/try-client-credentials-grant/

```
POST
https://<host>:<port>/oauth2/token
Authorization: Basic [Base64encode(Client-ID>:<ClientSecret>)]
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
```

Example:

```
POST
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
Authorization: Basic Q3g0TEtGTk9iZXVYb2N4N3hnT3B6NXZmekZvYTogVWRUNm5XbnFXWkdnNDFHWnI5TXBTWGs5eU04YQ==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
```